# Probability exercise: exchange uniform in a soccer match

Tags: probability, combinatorics

At the end of a soccer match, each of the 22 players exchanges the uniform of his own team randomly with one of the other 21 players (it means that if player A exchanges its uniform with player B, also B exchanges its uniform with A). Let $X$ be the number of players that after the exchange still wear the uniform of their original team. Compute

1) $P(X=7)$

2) $P(X=6)$

3) $P(X=8)$

I thought that $X=7$ and $X=6$ are impossible events, so that their probability is 0. I have lots of troubles for point 3). I'd like to compute this probability as

$\frac{\text{number of favourable cases}}{\text{total number of cases}}$.

I considered as total number of cases the number of possible couples of players, i.e. $\binom{22}{2}$. So, for instance, $P(X=0)=11^2/\binom{22}{2}$.

But, how can I compute the number of favourable couples for the event $X=8$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By symmetry (essentially the argument that rules out $X=7$ and $X=6$), there must be four players from each team that keep their colours. There are $11\choose 4$ ways to pick these in the first team and after that $3$ ways to pick the swapping partner of the alphabetically first of these players. The same goes for the other team. Finally, there are $(11-4)!$ ways to macth the remaining players with opponent players.

Comment: There is something that I don't understand.

Comment: Let me explain: 1) I guess you meant $(11-4)^2$ rather than $(11-4)!$. 2) When you do $\binom{11}{4}\times 3$ you count in this way more than once a given couple. For instance, call A, B, C, D, E the first five players of the first team; then, $\{A,B,C,D\}$ and $\{A,B,C,E\}$ are two of the $\binom{11}{4}$ possible combinations. So, when you perform $\binom{11}{4}\times 3$ you count twice the couple $AB$, $BC$ and $AC$. 3)Please, could you write your complete formula for $P(X=8)$?